# How do I get a list of packages installed by user?

Tags: package-management

I have seen many answers online, genrally giving complicated answers or saying it cant be done perfectly. However each of the answers isa few years old so I thought id ask here.

I want to include both programs installed from terminal and by downloads (e.g. steam)

edit: I only want what i directly installed not pre-installed or dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of installed packages using `apt`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to open `terminal` and run the command

```
apt list --installed
```

Comment: sorry, I want to know only what I have installed, not dependencies and pre-installed stuff